# Does the Android OS supports playing two or more audios simultaneously?

Tags: audio, stock-android

Does the Android OS supports playing two or more audios simultaneously ?

I am asking this because I have seen some apps playing audio without stopping the audio that's already playing in the background.

I am confused whether it is the feature of the app or the Android OS. Please provide some information about its support.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If the background music is played by App1 and the foreground music comes from App2 it is obviously a feature of the OS, because App1 can't access the audio of App2 and the other way round.